# Java ZonedDateTime to Instant conversion

Tags: java, java-8, jodatime

I am planning to convert ZonedDateTime to instant as per the below logic.

Say, I am in PST timeZone and the current time is 11A.M. If I convert now( no daylight saving as of today March 04 2018) and the toInstant will be 7P.M.

For the same 11 A.M, the toInstant will return 6 P.M as of April 04 2018 as daylight saving will be observed.

So, The below code returns correctly.

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();  --->>> March 04th 2018 at 11 A.M PST
dateTime.plusMonths(1).toInstant(); -->> returns April 04th 2018 at 6 PM PST as daylight saving will be observed
```

But,

The result will be different if i convert to Instant and then add a month.

```
Instant dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant();  --->>> March 04th 2018 at 7 P.M UTC
dateTime.plus(1,ChronoUnit.MONTHS).toInstant(); -->> returns April 04th 2018 at 7 PM UTC ( but the actual time should be 6 PM UTC ).
```

This is ok, as we already converted to UTC and it just adds from there.

Hence, To include the daylight saving time, I need to add days or months or years .... to ZonedDateTime and then convert to Instant.

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();   ---> March 04th 2018 at 11A.M
dateTime.plusDays(10).toInstant();     ---> March 14th 2018 at 6P.M
dateTime.plusMonths(1).toInstant();     ---> April 04th 2018 at 6P.M
```

The above code works as expected. But the below one is not returning 6P.M, But it returns 7P.M.

```
dateTime.plusSeconds(org.joda.time.Period.days(1).multipliedBy(10).toStandardSeconds().getSeconds())
         .toInstant())  --> ---> March 14th 2018 at 7P.M
```

Not sure, what is wrong with this and how to make it work with seconds.

Comment: There's no `ZoneDateTime` class and `Period` does not have a `public` `days` factory method.  Are you using something other than Java's API?  There's also no `toStandardSeconds` method.

Comment: Sorry, typo,... it is ZonedDateTime and the Period is from joda.time. Updated the Question now.

Comment: That makes more sense, but mixing two APIs like that is bound to produce unexpected results.  I recommend you try and recreate the issue with **just** Java's API.

Comment: I am using joda.time due to some other restriction.

Comment: I cant use java period, but trying to find a workaround.

Comment: Then are you able to recreate it with just `jodatime`?  If that's the case, I'd remove the `java-8` tag and replace it with `jodatime`.

Comment: Is there any solution with mixing these 2.

Comment: I wouldn't know, as they could be based on different standards.   If you're restricted to using `jodatime`, then stick with that and don't introduce another API.

Comment: This is reproducible using only the Java 8 java.time methods. Calling `Instant plusTenDaysInSeconds = zonedDateTime.plusSeconds(Duration.ofDays(10).getSeconds()).toInstant();` gives 2018-03-14T19:00:00Z, but calling `Instant plusTenDays = zonedDateTime.plusDays(10).toInstant();` gives 2018-03-14T18:00:00Z.

Comment: AFAIK there’s no direct conversion between Joda-Time and java.time types. So mixing them sounds like difficult.

Comment: @Bobulous This is the exact problem i have. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause is found in the documentation for the `ZonedDateTime` class. For the method `plusDays` we see this in the method documentation:

> This operates on the local time-line, adding days to the local date-time. This is then converted back to a ZonedDateTime, using the zone ID to obtain the offset.
>
> When converting back to ZonedDateTime, if the local date-time is in an overlap, then the offset will be retained if possible, otherwise the earlier offset will be used. If in a gap, the local date-time will be adjusted forward by the length of the gap.

However, in the documentation for the `plusSeconds` method we see this:

> This operates on the instant time-line, such that adding one second will always be a duration of one second later. This may cause the local date-time to change by an amount other than one second. Note that this is a different approach to that used by days, months and years.

So the two methods are designed to behave differently, and you need to consider this when choosing which method to use to suit your purpose.

Comment: My requirement is to add minutes or hours days or months to the ZonedDateTime. It works for plusDays, plusMonths. But, How can i make it work for plusHours & plusMinutes .... plusHours still not working as expected ....

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your requirement you have a number of minutes or hours to add to your time, for example

```
    long minutesToAdd = Duration.ofDays(10).toMinutes();
```

I am using java.time since I haven’t got experience with Joda-Time. Maybe you can translate my idea to Joda-Time if you wish.

As I further understand, the result of adding the above minutes should *not* be a point in time that number of minutes later. Instead it should work the same as adding 10 days. So if it’s 9 PM in California, you want 9 PM in California 10 days later. I suggest you solve this by converting to `LocalDateTime` before adding the minutes or hours, and then convert back to `ZonedDateTime` afterwards.

```
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
    System.out.println(now);
    System.out.println(now.toInstant());
    Instant inTenDays = now.toLocalDateTime()
            .plusMinutes(minutesToAdd)
            .atZone(now.getZone())
            .toInstant();
    System.out.println(inTenDays);
```

This just printed

```
2018-03-04T21:16:19.187690-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
2018-03-05T05:16:19.187690Z
2018-03-15T04:16:19.187690Z
```

Since summer time (DST) is in effect on March 15 (it is from March 11 this year), you don’t get the same hour-of-day in UTC, but instead the same hour-of-day in your time zone.